# Python AttributeError: Object has no Attribute pointing to constructor error

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, attributeerror

I am getting the following error when I try to run my PersonTest script:
AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'set_age'

This error occurred when I changed the line "self_age = age" to "self.set_age(age)" in my Person class file. When I change the line back, the error disappears but the exception for InvalidAge does not occur. The expected outcome is for my code to catch an exception when an age >120 is input by the user. I did what I believe to be the same thing with another class, Player, and accompanying test file, PlayerTest, but no such error occurred. I believe it's pointing to the constructor but I'm not sure if something isn't being passed correctly or some other issue? I've looked for spelling mistakes and indentation errors. I will include the code for the class and test that DOES work when I changed that single line as well.

The error traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\lsull\Documents\School\CS 119\Labs\Lab10\PersonTest.py", line 23, in 
> my_person = Employee(name, address, age, job_skills, yrs_worked)
> File "C:\Users\lsull\Documents\School\CS 119\Labs\Lab10\Employee.py", line 13, in **init**
> super().**init**(name, address, age)
> File "C:\Users\lsull\Documents\School\CS 119\Labs\Lab10\Person.py", line 13, in **init**
> self.set_age(age)
> AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'set_age'

The Person class:

```
from CustomExceptions import InvalidAge

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, address, age):
        self._name = name
        self._address = address
        self.set_age(age)

        # getter and setter methods for the various properties
        def get_name(self):
            return self._name

        def set_name(self, name):
            self._name = name

        def get_address(self):
            return self._address

        def set_address(self, address):
            self._address = address

        def get_age(self):
            return self._age

        def set_age(self, age):
            MIN_AGE = 0
            MAX_AGE = 120

            if age >= MIN_AGE and age <= MAX_AGE:
                self._age = age
            else:
                raise InvalidAge

    # instance method
    def to_string(self):
        return "Name: " + self._name + " Address: " + self._address + " Age: " + str(self._age)
```

The PersonTest script that gives me the error:

```
from Employee import Employee
from Student import Student
from CustomExceptions import InvalidAge
from CustomExceptions import InvalidYearsWorked
from CustomExceptions import InvalidUnits

# Try/except block
try:
    name = input("Enter name: ")
    address = input("Enter address: ")
    age = int(input("Enter age: "))
    job_skills = input("Enter job skills: ")
    yrs_worked = float(input("Enter years worked: "))

    # create an instance of an emplpoyee person
    my_person = Employee(name, address, age, job_skills, yrs_worked)

    # invoke the to_string() method and display everything
    print(my_person.to_string())

    name = input("\nEnter name: ")
    address = input("Enter address: ")
    age = int(input("Enter age: "))
    major = input("Enter major: ")
    units_completed = float(input("Enter units completed: "))

    # create an instance of a student person
    my_person = Student(name, address, age, major, units_completed)

    # invoke the to_string() method and display everything
    print(my_person.to_string())

# Exception handling, always go from most specific exception to most generic
except InvalidAge as e:
    print("Invalid age: ", e)
except InvalidYearsWorked as e:
    print("Invalid years worked: ", e)
except InvalidUnits as e:
    print("Invalid units completed: ", e)

# generic exception
#except Exception as ex:
    print("Generic exception: ", ex)
```

The Player class that had no issues when I changed the "self._number = number" to "self.set_number(number)":

```
from CustomExceptions import InvalidPlayerNumException

class Player:
    # custom constructor. Constructors are named __init__()
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        # set the attributes
        # note the single underscore _ before the variable name makes them protected
        self._name = name
        self.set_number(number) # note we call the setter method here


    # getter and setter methods for the various properties
    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def set_name(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def get_number(self):
        return self._number

    def set_number(self, number):
        MIN_NUMBER = 1
        MAX_NUMBER = 999

        # Add validation to make sure number is in the expected range
        if number >= MIN_NUMBER and number <= MAX_NUMBER:
            self._number = number
        else:
            # instead of setting player number to MIN_NUMBER, raise an exception
            #self._number = MIN_NUMBER # original code
            raise InvalidPlayerNumException


    # instance method
    def to_string(self):
        return "Name: " + self._name + " Number: " + str(self._number)
```

Finally, the PlayerTest script that runs fine with the Player class:

```
from BaseballPlayer import BaseballPlayer
from CustomExceptions import InvalidPlayerNumException
from CustomExceptions import InvalidBattingException

# Try/except block
try:
    name = input("Enter name: ")
    number = int(input("Enter number: "))
    position = input("Enter position: ")
    batting_avg = float(input("Enter batting average: "))

    # create an instance of a baseball player
    my_player = BaseballPlayer(name, number, position, batting_avg)

    # invoke the to_string() method and display everything
    print(my_player.to_string())

# Exception handling, always go from most specific exception to most generic
except InvalidPlayerNumException as e:
    print("Invalid player number: ", e)
except InvalidBattingException as e:
    print("Invalid batting avg: ", e)

# generic exception
except Exception as ex:
    print("Generic exception: ", ex)
```

Comment: Remove the `self` by lefting just `set_age(age)` as you defined it as a closure of the `__init__` method.